# How best to refresh a staging instance in EC2

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've been asked by a client to refresh their EC2 wordpress sites staging instance with their production data from a snaphot. I have the snapshot as a new volume but thats where I'm unsure of the next best step is to stop the staging instance and change to the new volume or if there will be more to it. The setup is old so there is nothing set up for automating it and its unlikely to be done again.

Comment: Is the staging instance purely used as a backup, or do they do work on it? If your goal is simply to copy Production to another instance, then the easiest way is to Create Image on the Production instance, which will generate an AMI. You can then launch a new instance from that AMI. It's not really "updating" a staging instance, but rather creating a new one. Alternatively, there is a new capability: [Amazon EC2 enables replacing root volumes for quick restoration](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/04/ec2-enables-replacing-root-volumes-for-quick-restoration-and-troubleshooting/)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The staging was used I think for development testing but we're trying to use it for a upgrade testing currently. I guess I can see about that route if the other won't work but we were seeing about using the existing AMI since its unused currently. Would it be better to do a whole new AMI or would swapping the volume be equivalent in this case?

Comment: Also I thought I saw the replace root only applied to snapshots for the current volume when I was looking at it.

Comment: For Amazon EC2, it has always been the case that it is better to launch a new instance. Swapping root volumes involves multiple steps (stop, detach, attach, start) compared to simply launching a new instance. The "replace" capability for root volumes is quite new.

Comment: Okay thank you; though just for reference does that mean that the stop, detach, attach, and start would accomplish the same result assuming the same at that time?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the same result assuming the same at that time". The full process would actually be: Take a snapshot of the production disk, create a new EBS volume from the snapshot, stop the 2nd instance, detach root disk from 2nd instance, attach new volume, start the 2nd instance, dispose of old disk from 2nd instance. Compare that to simply creating an AMI, then launching a new instance from the AMI and disposing of the old instance. Much simpler!